# How does Python's ipaddress module's summarize_address_range method approximate network ranges?

Tags: python, networking

There are of course a default set of ranges for different network classes, but CIDRs allow us to define virtually any network ranges we want. How does Python figure out the range just from high and low IPs?

Let's take an IP set I'm about to pass to python:

```
ip1 = ipaddress.IPV4Address('123.123.123.123')
ip2 = ipaddress.IPV4Address('123.123.143.143')
networks = [ipaddress.summarize_address_range(ip1, ip2)]
```

The theoretically, just knowing the high and low IP in the network doesn't tell us how the network is subdivided does it? The network admin could have divided the range in any number of ways. Yet in the limited cases I've tested, this code seems to produce accurate network structures. How does this work? Does Python actively query the internet to return whatever routing layout those networks are advertising? Or is it a guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, knowing the high and low is enough.  You can't have completely arbitrary subnets.  A subnet always contains a power of 2 addresses.  The bits that change between high and low determine the subnet mask, and that uniquely identifies the subnet.

If you have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.252, then there are 4 IP address, but the lowest one is reserved and the highest one is for broadcast, so there are two usable addresses.  So, if the low is 123.123.123.120 and the high is 123.123.123.123, then we know it is a 30/ subnet.  Notice the binary:

```
120 = 0111000
123 = 0111011
```

That's what tells us it's a 30/ netmask.

https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html